# Controller Properties ASP.NET Core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, properties, controller, asp.net-core

Have 2 pages for one long process. Both in one controller. My problem is:
In first page, using angular - run method that generate some data. Store that data in property in controller. Move to another page, using angular - run another method and that is... my data in property is null. Is there a solution to store data in controller properties in thid situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ASP.Net MVC, you can't store data in a property between 2 actions.

For achieving this, you have to use cache strategy.
Please, see this [link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-core-1-0).

Answer (score 1):

New instance of a controller is created on every request so whatever you save in property of your controller this will be destroyed together with a controller when request is ended. You have to store this data either on client(cookie, local storage) or server side (session, cache, database etc.).